# How to set the HTTP Keep-Alive timeout in a nodejs server

Tags: node.js, http-headers, express, keep-alive

I'm actually doing some load testing against an ExpressJS server, and I noticed that the response send by the server includes a "Connection: Keep-Alive" header. As far as I understand it, the connection will remain opened until the server or the client sends a "Connection: Close" header.

In some implementations, the "Connection: Keep-Alive" header comes up with a "Keep-Alive" header setting the connection timeout and the maximum number of consecutive requests send via this connection.

For example : "Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100"

Is there a way (and is it relevant) to set these parameters on an Express server ?

If not, do you know how ExpressJS handles this ?

**Edit:**
After some investigations, I found out that the default timeout is set in the [node standard http library](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L1688):

```
socket.setTimeout(2 * 60 * 1000); // 2 minute timeout
```

In order to change this:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end("Hello World");
}).on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.setTimeout(10000);
}).listen(3000);
```

Anyway it still looks a little bit weird to me that the server doesn't send any hint to the client concerning its timeout.

**Edit2:**
Thanks to josh3736 for his comment.

setSocketKeepAlive is not related to HTTP keep-alive. It is a TCP-level option that allows you to detect that the other end of the connection has disappeared.

Comment: Timeout is distinct from keepAliveTimeout,  socket.setTimeout cannot set the HTTP Keep-Alive timeout in a nodejs server.   You should use  server.keepAliveTimeout and turn TCP keepalive on at same time with using socket.setKeepAlive  https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_keepalivetimeout.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For   Express 3:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(5001);

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log("A new connection was made by a client.");
  socket.setTimeout(30 * 1000); 
  // 30 second timeout. Change this as you see fit.
});
```

Comment: Why are you listening twice there?

Comment: Does not work for me, the timeout got overridden after I set it. Setting `keepAliveTimeout` on the Server object did work though.

Comment: @Yogu where do you set `keepAliveTimeout`? Can you provide as another answer?

Comment: Why does this answer show how to do this for `express` when the question was for the base node.js `http` library? At the very least also show this for the base `http` module, even if you then go on to say "but you probably want to use express" (which some folks really don't because they need a base HTTP server purely for a protocol upgrade)

Comment: I'd love to understand what is actually going on here. What I am experiencing is when I take a really long time to process a request, eventually it looks like the request gets retried before I am finished processing the original request.

Comment: is this different from `app.request.setTimeout(30*1000);` ?

Comment: Timeout is distinct from keepAliveTimeout,  socket.setTimeout cannot set the HTTP Keep-Alive timeout in a nodejs server.   you should use  server.keepAliveTimeout https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_keepalivetimeout

Answer (score 15):

To set keepAliveTimeout on the express server do:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(5001);

server.keepAliveTimeout = 30000;
```

Answer (score 12):

For Node.js `10.15.2` and newer with express, only `server.keepAliveTimeout` was not enough. We also need to configure `server.headersTimeout` longer than `server.keepAliveTimeout`.

```js
server.keepAliveTimeout = 30000; 
// Ensure all inactive connections are terminated by the ALB, by setting this a few seconds higher than the ALB idle timeout
server.headersTimeout = 31000; 
// Ensure the headersTimeout is set higher than the keepAliveTimeout due to this nodejs regression bug: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27363
```

---

**Update**

Since this issue [Regression issue with keep alive connections](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27363) has been closed. We could just set `keepAliveTimeout` on the latest node.js version.

---

One more thing, If your node.js server is deployed under `AWS ELB` and encounters `502` error code occasionally.

```
Clients -> AWS ELB -> Node Server
```

AWS ELB has 60 seconds of connection idle timeout by default, and per   [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#connection-idle-timeout)

> We also recommend that you configure the idle timeout of your application to be larger than the idle timeout configured for the load balancer

Config the value of `keepAliveTimeout` to greater than 60 seconds could be one option to eliminate this issue.

Comment: this issue has now been resolved