# Nodejs and express server closes connection after 2 minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im using Express 4.X and node js 0.12.

One of my routes is for file uploading and processing and for some of the files the upload and process takes more than the 2 minutes default timeout. I have tried to settimeout to values more than 2 minutes but its just not working, the server closes connection exactly after 2 minutes every time.

```
server.timeout = 60 * 60 * 1000; // still closes after 2 minutes
server.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.setTimeout(700 * 1000); // still closes after 2 minutes
});

res.setTimeout(0);// still closes after 2 minutes
req.setTimeout(0);// still closes after 2 minutes
res.connection.setTimeout(0);// still closes after 2 minutes
```

The connect-timeout middleware is not helped either, it just keeps closing the connection after exactly 2 minutes. Tried changing the node version to older version but with no success.
Tried all the variations found online, but the connection still closes...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express.js Response Timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708208/express-js-response-timeout)

Comment: Tried that as-well, connect middleware results in the same 2 minute timeout...

Comment: Read the last answer from that page.

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure what you want me to read there. As i've already told, I have tried all their suggestions and none of them works.

Comment: If you're using Express 4.X where timeout middleware has been removed so need to manually add it.  You did that?

Comment: Yes I did, added the connect-timeout middleware. The same issue persists...

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: @scopsy Are you sure , is it a server-side issue? Because some browsers' http timeouts are 120000ms and some 300000ms.

Comment: req.setTimeout() is the only way which worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours of trying every answer available I had run an inspection with fiddler for that request. Turns out that in my development environment im using **browser-sync** for auto refreshing the browser window on any change. In fiddler i noticed that a long with the upload POST request browser-sync tied it to a socket connection which had 2 minute timeout.

after switched off the browser-sync proxy the very first solution worked like a charm.

```
server.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.setTimeout(600 * 60 * 1000); // now works perfectly...
})
```

Answer (score 16):

[server.setTimeout()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback) is the method that sets the HTTP connection timeout for all connections.

The 2 minutes are default.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Try this:

```js
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = module.exports.app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.setTimeout(10*60*1000); // 10 * 60 seconds * 1000 msecs
server.listen(appConfig.port, function () {
    var logger = app.get('logger');
    logger.info('**** STARTING SERVER ****');
});
```

Or this:

```
http.request(url).setTimeout()
```

Also, it can be a browser issue. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798707/browser-timeouts).

Comment: Tried that still closes connection after 120000ms

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
server.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.setTimeout(5 * 60 * 1000);
  socket.once('timeout', function() {
    process.nextTick(socket.destroy);
  });
});
```

Comment: As mentioned, the timeout middleware is not working as expected the connection closes after 2 minutes.

Comment: I saw it, so I was updating my answer, check now (:

Comment: Nope, still the same :( It's made me crazy, and the craziest part that before a month a go the socket.setTimeout() did fix thaht and suddenly 2 days ago it returned with no reason at all.

Comment: You want to close connection after 700 seconds?

Comment: I just want to make the default 2 minute timeout change to anything that will work (about 5 min is fine.)

Comment: scopsy, how about checking my answer? (:

Comment: The issue was with browser-sync all the time... it opened parallel socket to the request which i guess had internal timeout of 2 minutes regardless of the server config. After switching it off the initial socket.setTimeout(600 * 60 * 1000); works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks god, spent around 4 hours on that :(