# Messenger Bot "sleep mode" getaddrinfo

Tags: node.js, express, bots, messenger, superagent

I got a bot made in nodejs (expressjs) and hosted on my private VPS, I encounter a bug with HTTP request made with superagent lib.
When there is a long period of inactivity, the nodejs server is like in "sleep mode", and the first request is always an error caught in my try/catch, the error look like this : [image]

I got another bot hosted on heroku but I don't have this error, it seems it's maybe my VPS/Apache proxy ?

After the first request, when I made a new one, it works as expected. It's like my server is in "sleep mode" and the first request tell him to wake up.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Do a ping request every x minutes (or seconds) to keep your bot alive.

Comment: Yeah it may be a solutions, thanks for the idea :)

Comment: But it's a default behavior from the nodejs server in general  ?

Comment: Yes, and to prevent that, you may want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882507/nodejs-and-express-server-closes-connection-after-2-minutes

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: Tried and it works great !! No more error !  Cool, a nice things to know. You can post the response, so I can indicate that you have provided the answer. @C0dekid

Comment: Glad it worked! You can find my answer below, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal behaviour for NodeJS applications. To prevent the server for shutting down your application after inactivity, you can do a ping request every x minutes (or seconds) to keep your bot alive.

You can also use the `.setTimeout()` function.

```
server.setTimeout(10*60*1000);
```

Source: [Nodejs and express server closes connection after 2 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882507/nodejs-and-express-server-closes-connection-after-2-minutes)