# Server error in node.js application

Tags: arrays, node.js, localserver

I am getting the following error in my machine when I run my code locally.

```
The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 
bytes.
```

my code is a for loop which loops around 1 million time inserting objects in my array.

So what is the problem here please.

Comment: The problem is possibly a timeout?

Comment: Is it ?? how to change the timeout value in my local server?

Comment: It's just a hypothesis. To test it you could change your code temporarily to just insert a single object so it is finished quickly.

Comment: You are right @RobMeeuwisse, I am calling methods to do some calculations inside my loops, that's why it takes longer time...I tried to optimize them....so what to do if I have to keep them as is

Comment: It depends. I googled a bit, apparently you can set the response timeout if you are using ExpressJS, see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708208/express-js-response-timeout)

Comment: Another approach would be to store the incoming request in a database and respond quickly with 202 Accepted. Then in a background worker do the long running work for the request.

Comment: cool, I will try this also.... any other ideas :)