# Set server timeout in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I believe in node.js, there's a `server.timeout` setting.  Do you know how to set the server timeout in express.js?

Comment: I found this issue from the official Express GitHub page https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3330

Comment: Man can I have you kind comment on my answer ?

Answer (score 7):

```
var timeout = express.timeout // express v3 and below
var timeout = require('connect-timeout'); //express v4

app.use(timeout(120000));
app.use(haltOnTimedout);

function haltOnTimedout(req, res, next){
   if (!req.timedout) next();
}
```

#### Or without other modules

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
   res.setTimeout(120000, function(){
      console.log('Request has timed out.');
         res.send(408);
      });

      next();
 });
```

inspired by [Express.js Response Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708208/express-js-response-timeout)