# How to Set Request Timeout on Express 4.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I try to set request timeout to my function but it not working.

Here how I set timeout in my function.

```
app.post('upload', async (req, res) => {
   req.setTimeout(300000) // 5 minutes timeout
   ...
})
```

But the request still timeout on 2 minutes by default.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708208/express-js-response-timeout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express.js Response Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708208/express-js-response-timeout)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the same result :(