# Avoid abort of http requests that take long time in Node.js/Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm encountering a problem with http requests in my React/Nodejs app. When I'm trying to do a request that takes a long time (like 4 minutes or more) before sending response to the client the request is aborted. Is there any timeout for requests or something I'm not considering?
That's the response of my POST request: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Is there maybe something to handle with AbortController?

Comment: My guess is your server is killing the http request, not the client.

Comment: When the http request is sent I start a batch procedure in the server like that in a try catch block`await spawn(os_shell, ['/c', runFile], { stdio: 'inherit' });`  I'm using await-spawn module in node.

Comment: what is the timeout for express or whatever you are running?

Comment: Yes, I'm using express. How can I check or set the timeout?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708208/express-js-response-timeout

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Reviewed my answer title to center the problem.
I found a solution using `setTimeout()` in my Express.js. The problem was due to a server abort by the default express timeout.

I added this code in my server to resolve it. Hope this is usefull for someone:

```
const timeOut = 1000 * 60 * 10;
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.setTimeout(timeOut, () => {
        const error = new Error('Request Timeout.');
        err.status = 408;
        next(error);
    });
    res.setTimeout(timeOut, () => {
        const error = new Error('Request has expired.');
        err.status = 503;
        next(error);
    })
    next();
});
```