# how to set socket timeout in sails.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, sails.js

I build a project using sails.js , I have a request http://localhost:8005/auditAllUsers , which take above 2mins to get response back. 
I saw ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in chrome network .

I did some research , know how to do in nodejs with expressjs config

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('incoming');
    setTimeout(function(){
        res.send('hello world');},
    3000);//4000
});
var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('ready at 3000');
});

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log("A new connection was made by a client.");
  socket.setTimeout(4 * 1000); 

})
```

I read some [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651466/how-to-set-the-http-keep-alive-timeout-in-a-nodejs-server) , know that default timeout is: 2mins.

and some git [project](https://github.com/node-modules/agentkeepalive) may help, somehow I'm using sailsjs, these git project may not be helpful.

and saw  [sails config doc](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/sails.config/miscellaneous.html) , and put them in app.js:

```
sails.config.hookTimeout = 5000;
console.log('set hookTimeout');
// Start server
sails.lift(rc('sails'));
```

but have no luck.

and tried according to [sails socket doc](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.sockets.html)in config/socket.js:

```
onConnect: function(session, socket) {
    console.log("A new connection was made by a client.");
    socket.setTimeout(30 * 60 * 1000);
// By default, do nothing.

},
```

But the code did NOT log: console.log("A new connection was made by a client.");

So, what should I do with sails.js?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: This timeout is only for hooks timeout configurations, not http connection timeout, they are 2 different things