# angular $http call node js route

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I need to do angular $http request from client project to route in node js(server project),this request is long time request its supposed to take 10 min  or something like this.

The problem is that the client call the server side, and the client stops to wait to answer after 3 min,before the Node.js procedure finish.
I tried to set the angular $http request timeout to 1000000 but isn't working.

here is my code:

```
var deferred = this.q.defer();

var options = {
  method: "GET",
  timeout: 1000000,
  url: that.serverUrl + "excel" + that.urlParameterGet(true),
  responseType: 'blob'
};

this.http(options).then(function(data) {
  deferred.resolve(data);
}, function(error) {
  deferred.resolve(error);
});

return deferred.promise;
```

can someone help?
thanks

Comment: Try to raise the keep alive param on the server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651466/how-to-set-the-http-keep-alive-timeout-in-a-nodejs-server

Comment: Its working, thank you